# How to get the next token (int, float or string) from a file in Python?

Tags: python

Is there some way to just get the next token from a file in Python, as for example the Scanner class does in Java?

```
File file = new File("something");
Scanner myinput = new Scanner(file);
double a = myinput.nextDouble();
String s = myinput.next();
```

I'd like to ignore whitespaces, tabs, newlines and just get the next int/float/word from the file. I know I could read the lines and build something like Scanner myself, but I'd like to know if there isn't already something that I could use.

I've searched around but could only find line-oriented methods.

Thank you!

Comment: Do not use python reserved words as variable names. It's a common pitfall to redefine `in`, `str`, or `list` and later get funny error messages which may be hard to debug.

Comment: @cfi: thanks -- I have changed "in" to "input" in the example.

Comment: Shifted the problem from keyword to built-ins. You're safe since you're presumably on Python 2.*. In Python 3 `raw_input()` got replaced by `input()`. [Docs here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html). Lower case `scanner` might be safe...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the shlex-module in the standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html

```
import shlex
import StringIO # use in place of files

list(shlex.shlex(StringIO.StringIO('Some tokens. 123, 45.67 "A string with whitespace"')))
```

It does not handle floats the way you seem to want. Maybe you can extend or modify it.

Comment: Actually, it does handle floats!
Just set the attribute whitespace_split to True and it will parse dots as expected. :-) Thank you for that, it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: This is great. You can feed it with `sys.stdin` and get the next token using iteration or `get_token()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is really something around that sophisticated.

But you can take a look at the following options

- [`use re.split(pattern, string)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) and get what you want by providing regex's
- There is somewhere a [Scanner](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/457664/) class in the re module (but I don't think they developed it further)
- You could also consider using [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html) + [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html)
- Or as you yourself mentioned: Build one yourself, donate it do community and get famous ;)

Answer (score 0):

if your file is *.ini alike text files, you could use ConfigParser module

There is few examples out there.

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

and pyparsing will do that for other purpose, I think. 
I havn't use pyparsing before, so I have no clue right now.

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can take a look at [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)